# Disposing Apache FTP object after use

Tags: java, ftp

I'm trying to delete some files I have temporarily created and uploaded with the apache commons ftp-class.

```
FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
ftp.login(user, password);

/* Some FTP-Operations in between... not really important*/

File uploadFile = new File("tempfile.txt");

/* Filling the file here... */

ftp.storeFile(uploadFile.getName(), new FileInputStream(uploadFile));

/* Some more operations on FTP and Filesystem */

uploadFile.delete();
```

`uploadFile.delete();` returns `false`. If the line

```
ftp.storeFile(uploadFile.getName(), new FileInputStream(uploadFile));
```

is left out, the deletion works perfectly fine.

I have also tried to disconnect before I delete the file:

```
ftp.logout();
ftp.disconnect();
```

Still no luck.

However, if I force the garbage collector to run

```
System.gc();
System.runFinalization();
```

The file can be deleted after the upload.

The problem now is: I was given to unterstand that you can't really force the garbage collection. You can merely suggest it. So, it's not a save bet.

Is there a way to dispose the ftp-object in any way? It does not have a `dispose()` oder `flush()` method or anything.

Or is it really the correct and "professional" way to call the garbage collector and hope for the best?